# Is the iodide and persulfate reaction bimolecular?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry, kinetics

Given the following reaction in an aqueous state:
$$ \mathrm{2I^- + S_2O_8^{-2}\rightarrow  I_2 + 2SO_4^{2-}}$$
Is it bimolecular o trimolecular? Because two molecules of iodide react with one molecule of persulfate, so I would say trimolecular. 
Furthermore, I know it is a second order reaction because of the Iodide Clock experiment I performed, so would that mean that the reaction is complex and not an elementary reaction?

Comment: You already know the answer. Just say it.

Comment: So are my assumptions correct?

Comment: Which one? You have experimental evidence, trust it.

Comment: Yes, but a second order reaction does not imply is bimolecular if the reaction is not elementary

Comment: Not exactly. Bimolecular or trimolecular is not  relevant for nonelementar reactions. If the whole complex reaction is of second order, then it's usually a safe bet that there is no trimolecular elementar reaction in it.